# Raphael JS legend font

Tags: raphael

Any ways to change the legend font size in raphael.js for making pie chart (g.raphael.js, g.pie.js)? I've found similar question here but there's no working solution for me. So anyone has any idea about it then share please.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by adding in your legend the following:

```
legend: 
{
    ...
    labelFont: '10px Tahoma'
},
```

Hope this helped ;)

Also, for `pie`s try

> **label: { font: '12px Tahoma' }**